# Python - Cut all words between two Strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

Could someone help me to cut all the strings between JOIN and ON keyword in addition to first line using Python 3?

INPUT DATA ASSIGNED TO VARIABLE

```
input_txt=
date_dim date_dim_all
INNER JOIN main_fact_response
  ON (date_dim_all.response_date = main_fact_response.response_date)
LEFT JOIN dim_fore_main
  ON (dim_fore_main.id = fact_fore_respond.id)
LEFT JOIN fact_fore_resi
  ON (fact_fore_resi.fore_re = fact_fore_respond.fore_re
INNER JOIN fact_fore_respond fact_fore_respond_merit
  ON (
      fact_fore_respond_merit.fore_respond = fact_fore_r
espond.fore_respond
```

OUTPUT DATA

```
date_dim date_dim_all,
main_fact_response,
dim_fore_main,
fact_fore_resi,
fact_fore_respond fact_fore_respond_merit
```

Comment: and where to admire please what you've tried yet to get **your** task done?

Comment: I can able to fetch all the string between JOIN and ON keyword. Is there any way to include the strings before the first INNER JOIN as well. x = re.findall(r'JOIN(.*?)ON',data,re.DOTALL)
print(x)

Comment: then add your code to your question, pls. Properly formatted. The way you formulated your question it looks like an assignment for a free-of-charge coding service.

Answer (score 0):

```
 input_data = '''date_dim date_dim_all
    INNER JOIN main_fact_response
      ON (date_dim_all.response_date = main_fact_response.response_date)
    LEFT JOIN dim_fore_main
      ON (dim_fore_main.id = fact_fore_respond.id)
    LEFT JOIN fact_fore_resi
      ON (fact_fore_resi.fore_re = fact_fore_respond.fore_re
    INNER JOIN fact_fore_respond fact_fore_respond_merit
      ON (
          fact_fore_respond_merit.fore_respond = fact_fore_r
    espond.fore_respond'''  


input_data = input_data.replace("JOIN","cuthere")
input_data = input_data.replace("ON","cuthere")
data_list = input_data.split('cuthere')
data_list = data_list[1::2]
#The Next Part Of The Code Is Needed Only Because Your String Is Multiline .
i = 0
for i < len(data_list):
      data_list[i] = data_list[i].strip()
```